# Ubuntu wired ethernet can be detected but can't connect to any other divice with RX data transfer always zero

Tags: linux, ubuntu, embedded, ethernet

### Platform

- CPU: RK3288 ARMv7 embedded processor
- Memory: 2GB
- NIC: RTL8211E chip on board
- OS: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

```
root@9tripod:~# uname -a
Linux 9tripod 3.10.0 #26 SMP PREEMPT Sat Mar 4 17:06:44 CST 2017 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
root@9tripod:~# cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS \n \l
```

### Symptoms

After system image flashed and system booted, a net cable was connected between a PC and the board. Then static IP address was set to the PC and the board using `ifconfig`:

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.XXX netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Then I tried `ping` my PC but can't reach:

```
root@9tripod:~# ping 192.168.1.107
PING 192.168.1.107 (192.168.1.107) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.233 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.233 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.233 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.233 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.233 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.233 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.1.107 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, +6 errors, 100% packet loss, time 6005ms
pipe 3
```

After some attempts, I found the green LED on RJ45 connector on the board was blinking while yellow LED kept off. But once net cable plugged out, both two LEDs kept on. Then by typing `ifconfig` command, I found no any RX packets transfered:

```
root@9tripod:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ee:e3:d4:01:f6:6f
          inet6 addr: fe80::ece3:d4ff:fe01:f66f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2133 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:524034 (524.0 KB)
          Interrupt:59
...
```

When pinging reversely using the PC, it showed "Destination host unreachable" and no any packages received by the board as well.
I tried rebooting system, changing another cable and using a switch, even the RJ45 connector was replaced by a new one, but none of them worked. Btw, wlan0 was down when I test ping, so there should not be a problem with route table.

### Diagnose Infomation

1. Using `ifconfig` : see symptoms sector.
2. Using `ip link show`:

```
root@9tripod:~# ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ee:e3:d4:01:f6:6f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: sit0: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:90:4c:11:22:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

3. Contents in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
root@9tripod:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

4. Using net manager:

```
root@9tripod:~# nmcli device status
DEVICE     TYPE              STATE
eth0       802-3-ethernet    disconnected
wlan0      802-11-wireless   connected
root@9tripod:~# nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            stmmaceth
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        EE:E3:D4:01:F6:6F

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           1000 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on
...
```

5. Using `mii-tool`:

```
root@9tripod:~# mii-tool
eth0: negotiated 1000baseT-FD flow-control, link ok
```

6. Using `ethtool`:

```
root@9tripod:~# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP AUI BNC MII FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: external
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: ug
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x0000003f (63)
                               drv probe link timer ifdown ifup
        Link detected: yes
```

7. Using `dmesg`:

```
root@9tripod:~# dmesg |grep -i eth0
[   17.685231] eth0: device MAC address ee:e3:d4:01:f6:6f
[   17.693782] eth0: PHY ID 001cc915 at 0 IRQ 0 (stmmac-0:00) active
[   17.693788] eth0: PHY ID 001cc915 at 1 IRQ 0 (stmmac-0:01) active
```

### Question

Since system detected eth0 and can perform operations above without error and IP address was staticly set correctly, what caused the board can't access any other devices via eth0?

I guess there may be something wrong with the NIC chip, but it's strange that Linux can operate it with no error. Is it possile that a chip works overall normanl but certain part of it's function like data receive get broken?

If any other diagnose infomation should be provided please leave a comment. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: How about the opposite direction, pinging the embedded machine from your  PC?

Comment: @Philippos  Ping using a Windows PC showed "Destination host unreachable" and no any packages received by the embedded board checking by using `ifconfig`.

Comment: Is the PHY communication set up correctly (MMI for 1000baseT?!). Maybe the network experts on https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ are better qualified to narrow the problem with your excellent pre-analysis.